# Keyboard does not work in MokManager during key enrollment

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, secure-boot

I am trying to enroll a MOK under Ubuntu 20.04.1 for supporting some third-party kernel modules while keeping Secure Boot enabled. The system boots fine with the stock kernel and modules, but I am having issues with using the Mok Manager to enroll the generated MOK that is being used to sign third-party kernel modules. When I start the enrollment process, I enter a password into the dialog while Ubuntu is running and it schedules for the Mok Manager to run on next boot to continue the enrollment process. When I reboot, I find myself in the Mok Management menu with four choices, the first being to continue boot and the second to enroll the generated MOK key. However, my keyboard does not seem to function at all during this time. Not even Caps Lock or Num Lock takes effect. If I wait long enough, it seems to time out and continue boot asking me to press any key to enter into the Mok Manager. I have found that F1 and F12 seem to enter into it, both keys that can be used to select BIOS options, but most other keys are still ignored.

From Grub or other bootloaders, my laptop keyboard seems to work fine. An external USB keyboard did not help. This is a Lenovo Legion Y540.

Is there something blocking the keyboard or something that needs to be loaded to enable it?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you come across any information to help you with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: Enter BIOS, this enabled the keyboard in MOK Manager for me. You don't need to change any setting there, you can directly exit it after entering it.

I had the same problem after installing Linux Mint 20.1 on my Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 16ACH6H.

After MOK Manager started it didn't recognize my keyboard. I had to shortly press the power button to turn it of. Now I turned it on, pressed F2 to get into my BIOS (the keyboard is working there). I directly left the BIOS without changing anything and voilà - the keyboard was working then!

Linux Mint will only show the MOK Manager twice, if it isn't shown to you anymore you can bring it back by executing the following command from your Terminal:

`sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key`

You need to press `<Tab>` to get to the "Ok", then enter any password, repeat and then shut down. Turn it on again and don't forget to enter the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the answer given by RafaelKr, about forcing the system to go through the Bios configuration before allowing it to proceed to the MOK manager, but in my case I also had to make sure that my Lenovo Legion 5 17ARH05H had the most recent BIOS installed.

Prior to the BIOS update (with older BIOS version FSCN14WW) this procedure did finally allow the MOK manager to see keyboard presses, but the MOK manager displayed an alternate menu which did not include the option of easily importing the new MOK key.

After I updated to BIOS version FSCN18WW, it was still necessary to go through BIOS configuration to get a live keyboard, but then I actually did see the correct MOK manager screen with the expected entries, and it all worked as expected to install the new keys.